# How to make custom Bottom Navigation Bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bottomappbar

I have a design of Bottom Navigation Bar like this:

[image]

I try my best to create custom of Bottom Navigation Bar with this code:

```
class FABBottomAppBarItem {
  FABBottomAppBarItem({this.iconData, this.text});
  IconData iconData;
  String text;
}

class FABBottomAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
  FABBottomAppBar({
    this.items,
    this.centerItemText,
    this.height: 60.0,
    this.iconSize: 24.0,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.color,
    this.selectedColor,
    this.notchedShape,
    this.onTabSelected,
  }) {
    assert(this.items.length == 2 || this.items.length == 4);
  }
  final List<FABBottomAppBarItem> items;
  final String centerItemText;
  final double height;
  final double iconSize;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Color color;
  final Color selectedColor;
  final NotchedShape notchedShape;
  final ValueChanged<int> onTabSelected;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => FABBottomAppBarState();
}

class FABBottomAppBarState extends State<FABBottomAppBar> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  _updateIndex(int index) {
    widget.onTabSelected(index);
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> items = List.generate(widget.items.length, (int index) {
      return _buildTabItem(
        item: widget.items[index],
        index: index,
        onPressed: _updateIndex,
      );
    });
    items.insert(items.length >> 1, _buildMiddleTabItem());

    return BottomAppBar(
      shape: widget.notchedShape,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: items,
      ),
      color: widget.backgroundColor,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMiddleTabItem() {
    return Expanded(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: widget.height,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: widget.iconSize),
            Text(
              widget.centerItemText ?? '',
              style: TextStyle(color: widget.color),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTabItem({
    FABBottomAppBarItem item,
    int index,
    ValueChanged<int> onPressed,
  }) {
    Color color = _selectedIndex == index ? widget.selectedColor : widget.color;
    return Expanded(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: widget.height,
        child: Material(
          type: MaterialType.transparency,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () => onPressed(index),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(item.iconData, color: color, size: widget.iconSize),
                Text(
                  item.text,
                  style: TextStyle(color: color),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I implemented that custom like this:

```
bottomNavigationBar: FABBottomAppBar(
          centerItemText: 'เสา',
          color: Colors.grey,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          selectedColor: Colors.red,
          notchedShape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          onTabSelected: _onTapped,
          items: [
            FABBottomAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.home, text: 'หน้าแรก'),
            FABBottomAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.search, text: 'ค้นหา'),
            FABBottomAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.account_circle, text: 'โปรไฟล์'),
            FABBottomAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.more_horiz, text: 'อื่นๆ'),
          ],
        ),
        body: _list[_page],
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          elevation: 2.0,
        ),
      ),
```

And the result of that code is:

[image]

How to make my Custom Nav Bar like the design? Because in the design, the `FAB/Asset/Icon` inside the Bottom Navigation Bar and have `curved upwards` as I marked with `arrows` in the design.

Comment: Check this : https://proandroiddev.com/flutter-how-to-using-bottomappbar-75d53426f5af

Comment: Please see the `design` and the result of https://proandroiddev.com/flutter-how-to-using-bottomappbar-75d53426f5af, it's different in the `middle of FAB`. I already add `arrows` to the design to `make sure not missing`. In the design, in middle of FAB has `curved upwards`. But the result that I code and that you give the link, `not have the curved upwards`.

Comment: Find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57917876/how-to-add-floating-action-button-in-bottom-navigation-bar-in-center-with-border

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I edited CircularNotchedRectangle.

Use `CircularOuterNotchedRectangle` instead of `CircularNotchedRectangle`.

PS. I added extraOffset param for extra thick. but it's not working exactly correct. But I just wanted to show you how to approach.

```dart
class CircularOuterNotchedRectangle extends NotchedShape {
  /// Creates a [CircularOuterNotchedRectangle].
  ///
  /// The same object can be used to create multiple shapes.
  const CircularOuterNotchedRectangle({this.extraOffset = 10.0});

  final double extraOffset;

  /// Creates a [Path] that describes a rectangle with a smooth circular notch.
  ///
  /// `host` is the bounding box for the returned shape. Conceptually this is
  /// the rectangle to which the notch will be applied.
  ///
  /// `guest` is the bounding box of a circle that the notch accommodates. All
  /// points in the circle bounded by `guest` will be outside of the returned
  /// path.
  ///
  /// The notch is curve that smoothly connects the host's top edge and
  /// the guest circle.
  // TODO(amirh): add an example diagram here.
  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect host, Rect guest) {
    if (guest == null || !host.overlaps(guest)) return Path()..addRect(host);

    // The guest's shape is a circle bounded by the guest rectangle.
    // So the guest's radius is half the guest width.
    final double notchRadius = guest.width / 2.0;

    // We build a path for the notch from 3 segments:
    // Segment A - a Bezier curve from the host's top edge to segment B.
    // Segment B - an arc with radius notchRadius.
    // Segment C - a Bezier curve from segment B back to the host's top edge.
    //
    // A detailed explanation and the derivation of the formulas below is

    const double s1 = 15.0;
    const double s2 = 1.0;

    final double r = notchRadius + extraOffset/2;
    final double a = -1.0 * r - s2;
    final double b = host.top + guest.center.dy;

    final double n2 = math.sqrt(b * b * r * r * (a * a + b * b - r * r));
    final double p2xA = ((a * r * r) - n2) / (a * a + b * b);
    final double p2xB = ((a * r * r) + n2) / (a * a + b * b);
    final double p2yA = math.sqrt(r * r - p2xA * p2xA) - extraOffset/2;
    final double p2yB = math.sqrt(r * r - p2xB * p2xB) - extraOffset/2;

    final List<Offset> p = List<Offset>(6);

    // p0, p1, and p2 are the control points for segment A.
    p[0] = Offset(a - s1, b);
    p[1] = Offset(a, b);
    p[2] = p2yA > p2yB ? Offset(p2xA, -p2yA) : Offset(p2xB, p2yB);

    // p3, p4, and p5 are the control points for segment B, which is a mirror
    // of segment A around the y axis.
    p[3] = Offset(-1.0 * p[2].dx, -p[2].dy);
    p[4] = Offset(-1.0 * p[1].dx, p[1].dy);
    p[5] = Offset(-1.0 * p[0].dx, p[0].dy);

    // translate all points back to the absolute coordinate system.
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i += 1) p[i] += guest.center;

    return Path()
      ..moveTo(host.left, -host.top)
      ..lineTo(p[0].dx, p[0].dy)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(p[1].dx, p[1].dy, p[2].dx, -p[2].dy)
      ..arcToPoint(
        p[3],
        radius: Radius.circular(notchRadius),
        clockwise: true,
      )
      ..quadraticBezierTo(p[4].dx, p[4].dy, p[5].dx, p[5].dy)
      ..lineTo(host.right, host.top)
      ..lineTo(host.right, host.bottom)
      ..lineTo(host.left, host.bottom)
      ..close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this custom code is working!!. But, can I change the position of FAB to bottom? So the FAB can parallel to other icons like in the design

Comment: @RRifaFauziKomara I know it's late reply. Use this below in the floatActionButton.

```InkWell(child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top:30),
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffff6666), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
          ), onTap: (){
            //do
          },)
```

Answer (score 5):

Please  try this one, its may helps you

```
 Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    floatingActionButton: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 70,
        width: 70,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Container(
            height: 75,
            width: 75,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 4),
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
             color: Colors.red
            ),
            child: Icon(Icons.add, size: 40),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    bottomNavigationBar: new Container(
      height: 80.0,
      color: Colors.white,
      padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
      child: new Theme(

        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          // sets the background color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
            canvasColor: Colors.white,
            // sets the active color of the `BottomNavigationBar` if `Brightness` is light
            primaryColor: Colors.red,
            bottomAppBarColor: Colors.green,
            textTheme: Theme
                .of(context)
                .textTheme
                .copyWith(caption: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))), // sets the inactive color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
        child:
        new BottomNavigationBar(
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            currentIndex:0 ,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
                  title: new Text('Home'),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
                title: new Text('Search'),
              ),
BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border,color: Colors.transparent,),
                  title: Text('Center')
              ),

              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
                  title: Text('Person')
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
                  title: Text('More')
              ),

            ]),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: how remove the click on the center tab item ?

Comment: This is a hacky solution but it almost works for me. Need to think of a way to remove the ink effect from the center tab item though.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably wrap your FloatingActionButton in a ClipRRect and Container like

```
  floatingActionButton: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
```

Giving as color same of the BottomNavigationBoar. It should work

Comment: It's not working. Because have a `space` between navbar and FAB

Comment: @R Rifa Fauzi Komara You can use FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked