# how to Custom Bottom Navigation Bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-bottomnav

Can anyone help me how to achieve this customized bottom navigation bar in my app? I am new to flutter.
[image]

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59820088/2804581

Comment: @Shammah, go through this url and try to build bottom bar using verious packages

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package named convex_bottom_bar to achieve very similar style.

https://pub.dev/packages/convex_bottom_bar